# How to improve an IF statement in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

Consider the mysql

```
SELECT If(
            (SELECT `price` FROM `prices` AS `B` WHERE `A`.`Item_ID` = `B`.`Item_ID`)<5,
            5,
            (SELECT `price` FROM `prices` AS `B` WHERE `A`.`Item_ID` = `B`.`Item_ID`)
        ) AS `Item_Price' 
FROM `items` AS `A`
```

where it used to find the price from `prices` table for each item from the `items` table, and If the price is less than 5, then it is to 5. The problem with this is that if the `IF` statement comes false, i.e. the price greater or equal to 5, then it runs another search for the same price which may slow down the page. Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `LEFT JOIN` instead of a sub-query:

```
SELECT If(COALESCE(`price`, 0) < 5, 5, `price`) AS `Item_Price' 
FROM `items` AS `A`
LEFT JOIN `prices` AS `B` ON `A`.`Item_ID` = `B`.`Item_ID`
```

This assumes that there is a one-to-one relationship between `items` and `prices` based on `Item_ID`. If your initial query runs without problems and your sub-query returns just a scalar value, so such a one-to-one relationship indeed exists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

select 
    case
        when b.price < 5 then 5
        else b.price
    end
from items a
left join prices b on b.Item_ID = a.Item_ID